# Intuition: Topological notion of genus and Genus as the dimension of the complex vector space of holomorphic differentials

Tags: differential-forms, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

In my self-study of Lec.7 of [Belyi Maps and Dessins d'Enfants](https://math.mit.edu/%7Esschiavo/Courses/Belyi-Sp21/index.php), I came across the following statement

> Definition 3: Genus can be defined as the dimension of the complex vector space of holomorphic differentials.

Followed by the remark saying that

> Remark 4: One can show that this agrees with the topological notion of genus.

Can someone point me to some work or book that helps me to understand this...?
Or just answering what this is also super-appreciated!!

Thank you for taking time to check my post!

Comment: I guess this is a consequence of Riemann-Roch. Someone with more familiarity with complex geometry can provide details.

Comment: Got it! I think I'll read the lecture notes further to see how the discussion develops as well!